# looking for a java library with a simple to calculate tf–idf, term frequency–inverse document frequency

Tags: java, nlp, tf-idf

I need to calculate tf-idf for a set of documents and am looking for a java library that does this.

NOTE: I am aware of Mahout but I really want is a library with a simple interface and one that does not require infrastructure setup.

Comment: The classes in Mahout are just simple calls to Lucene. They require no infrastructure, especially if you *read them* (they are open source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mahout is easy to use and install. All you need is JDK environment and maven.
[how to install mahout](http://nivirao.blogspot.com/2012/04/installing-apache-mahout-on-ubuntu.html)

Also you could use hadoop with mahout, which is not a must (you could run mahout locally without hadoop). However you could find this [blog](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) helpful for install hadoop.

Comment: can you help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837788/how-can-i-calculate-total-number-of-term-frequency-in-all-collection-s-document